# Accessing objects of environment in R using quantmod library

Tags: r, environment, quantmod

I have some experience in R but so far never used my own environment. Over the last months I had to use my own environment from time to time and I have some questions about it.

- The main reason for using an environment as "data-container" is
  because it is much faster then others, right? For example, using the
  `quantmod` why do we load OHLC objects into an environment by using
  `getSymbols`?

Having such a new environment coming from `getSymbols`, i.e.

```
tick = c( "VNO" , "VMC" , "WMT" , "WAG") 
data.env <- new.env()    start<-as.Date("2013-01-01")   
getSymbols(tick,env=data.env,src="yahoo",from=start)
```

How can we efficiently access members in data.env, e.g. if we want to check if all members in data.env are OHLC objects can we do something like: `is.OHLC(data[[all elements]])`?

Moreover, for the above examples of data, how can I calculate the Value at Risk for such a portfolio. My idea was to us the function `VaR` from the `PerformanceAnalytics` library. The help page of `VaR` says as argument: "an xts, vector, matrix, data frame, timeSeries or zoo object of asset returns". For this purpose I wanted to use `dailyReturn` to get the returns, which then can be used for the function `VaR`. However `dailyReturn` needs an OHLC object as argument. Hence I can calculate `VaR` as soon as I know how to turn the elements in `data.env` to a OHLC matrix

Comment: You can use `eapply` to sift through the objects in that environment.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik the problem is I don't want to have a list as value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The main reason for using an environment as "data-container" is
>   because it is much faster then others, right?

No, I think the main reason is to keep things clean and avoid overwriting objects in your global environment. (In addition, to have all "new" objects as a "bundle" instead of several separate objects. For this purpose, a list would serve as well but see below for the differences between lists and environments.) With your call to getSymbols, four new objects are created:

```
"VMC" "VNO" "WAG" "WMT"
```

If these objects were created in your global environment (aka workspace), any pre-existing objects with the same names would be overwritten. (This happens when you use `load` ... for example, you have `x` in your workspace and also saved in a file named "x.rda". After `load("x.rda")` the previous version of `x` in your workspace is lost.)

Environments are not like ordinary R objects - because you can have different names pointing to the same environment. For example, if x is any kind of object in R, then assigning  `y <- x` creates a copy of x. Not with environments:

```
> ls(data.env)
[1] "VMC" "VNO" "WAG" "WMT"
> yummy <- data.env
> yummy$x <- "bingo"
> ls(data.env)
[1] "VMC" "VNO" "WAG" "WMT" "x"  
> data.env$x
[1] "bingo"
> data.env$x <- "Florida"
> yummy$x
[1] "Florida"
> with(yummy, rm(x))
> ls(data.env)
[1] "VMC" "VNO" "WAG" "WMT"
```

Here when we assign `yummy <- data.env` we do not create a copy of data.env but just another pointer to the same object. So when we do something in `yummy` the same will happen in `data.env`.

> How can we efficiently access members in data.env, e.g. if we want to
>   check if all members in data.env are OHLC objects can we do something
>   like: is.OHLC(data[[all elements]])?

As suggested above, `eapply` is the answer, - use `unlist` for converting the resulting list to avector if you like:

```
unlist(eapply(data.env, is.OHLC))
```

Finally, you can fetch the objects directly to your workspace like this:

```
getSymbols(tick,env=.GlobalEnv,src="yahoo",from=start)
```

This is probably not slower for most purposes but the downside is that you can't then easily access the four new objects together (for example, deleting them, or `eapply`'ing something). And you will have to make sure that you have nothing worthwhile in your workspace before you do it, because, potentially, everything can be overwritten.

Comment: So an environmwnet is like a reference in c++?

Comment: I don't really know about references in c++. In R they say, environments use "pass-by-reference semantics" - and this is used in clever ways in e.g package `proto` as well as reference classes (see `?ReferenceClasses`)

Answer (score 1):

As Roman suggested the easiest method to check if a certain object in your data environment is an OHLC object is by using eapply like so:

```
eapply(data.env,is.OHLC)
```

which returns a list of your objects in your data environment and a logical value if it is a OHLC object or not. If you want to see a more compact form you can wrap `"str"` around the expression. For example to see which of the objects in my current data environment are OHLC-objects I can do the following:

```
> str(eapply(data,is.OHLC))
List of 9
 $ VXZlong        : logi TRUE
 $ prices         : logi FALSE
 $ XIVlong        : logi TRUE
 $ dates          : logi FALSE
 $ VXXlong        : logi TRUE
 $ weight         : logi FALSE
 $ ZIVlong        : logi TRUE
 $ symbolnames    : logi FALSE
 $ execution.price: logi FALSE
```